# Path to camera folder on iOS8?

Tags: path, ios8, directory

I would like to load an image from the camera folder on iOS 8.
What is the path to the folder where the camera images are stored in?

Comment: i think you need itunes for it

Comment: which iDevice are you using?

Comment: @Mohit_Bhasi iPhone 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The full path to the **Camera Roll directory on iOS** is the following:*

```
/private/var/mobile/MEDIA/DCIM/
```

Comment: I don't mean the path on Mac or PC but on the iPhone itself. Is that the same?

Comment: @Tom  edited the answer to your liking. Helpful? please upvote and mark as answer